# HIVE column alias not showing in output when queried on same table

Tags: sql, hive, average, alias

Working on HIVE exercise.

I have a table movierating with fields as movieid, rating. I need to write to query to find out the average rating of movies having rating more than 2. 
Output format expected: |Movieid|average rating|
The data :

```
movie1 2
movie1 3
movie1 5
movie2 4
movie2 5
movie3 6
movie3 3
movie6 2
movie6 3
```

output expected is: average rating for movies, for which rating is greater than 2.
Movieid  average rating
movie2   4.5
movie3   4.5

My this query is not working. It is not showing the column alias names at all. I tried giving `` as well. but in vain.

```
select movieid as Movieid, avg(rating) as averagerating
from movierating
where movieid not in (select m.movieid
                      from movierating m
                      where m.rating <= 2
                     )
group by movieid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the edition. I shall try to follow these guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> output expected is: average rating for movies, for which rating is greater than 2.

I am interpreting the question as "the average rating is greater than 2".  If so, use `having`:

```
select movieid, avg(rating) as averagerating
from movierating
group by movieid
having averagerating > 2;
```

If you want the average rating of movies only considering ratings greater than 2, then use `where`:

```
select movieid, avg(rating) as averagerating
from movierating
where rating > 2
group by movieid;
```

Comment: I had tried out these basic queries, but in vain. I need the column name and also the movies with rating 2 should be avoided. I have given more samples in the input. Could you please assist. ?